# MoviePy not displaying non-English characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, imagemagick, moviepy

I'm trying to display non English characters in movie py but it's not displaying the actual character I typed. The language I'm trying is Telugu. What is the problem in displaying the characters?
This is the code I'm using

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from moviepy.editor import *

# create clip from image
clip = ImageClip('img/1.jpg').on_color((1920, 1080))
clip = clip.set_duration(2)

# add annotation to clip
txtclip = TextClip('n+<ý² yûTq¿£yû', fontsize=50, color='red', font="Deepika")
cvc = CompositeVideoClip([ clip, txtclip.set_pos(('center', 'bottom'))])
cvc = cvc.set_duration(2)

# write video to file
cvc.write_videofile("text.mp4", fps=24)
```

The characters(Language) displayed in the code is weird but when I copy the text from the original file which was different characters displayed as this. And this worked in displaying the text in PySide QLabel.

**Its just displaying boxes instead of the characters.**

Can anyone help me with this issue?[For your reference I'm adding image of text displayed in the code for language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xzBC.jpg)

Comment: Uff, python 2. Can you try passing a unicode string to `TextClip`? (Like `TextClip(u'n+<ý² yûTq¿£yû')`)

Comment: Yes I tried this as well but it didn't worked

text = u'n+<ý² yûTq¿£yû'.encode('utf-8')

Comment: Can anyone suggest me a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I printed Japanese characters, but they were not displayed in video.

The problem was that the font did not support these characters.

Thus this produced empty result:

```
my_text = mp.TextClip("すみません。お先に失礼します",
          font= "Amiri-regular", color= "white", fontsize= 34)
```

Solution was to download a custom font and import it as in example:

```
my_text2 = mp.TextClip("すみません。お先に失礼します",
           font="wqy-microhei.ttc", color="white", fontsize=34)
```

I downloaded this font from github and it can be simply placed into directory with the python source code to be imported.